# Как правильно указать пути к файлам?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Как мне правильно указать пути к файлам в Джанго? Есть два джанго-приложения: в одном находится conversations.html `D:\Project\Project\pages\templates\conversations`, в другом ChatLogic.js `D:\Project\Project\chat\js`. Мне нужно подключить к html js. В settings.py я не уверен в правильности написания путей.

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

и

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'chat/js'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'chat/css'),
]
```

Также в html я написал:

```
<script src="{% static 'chat/js/ChatLogic.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'chat/css/chat-style.css' %}">
```

,что тоже не является правильным, ведь у меня эти файлы не находятся в static.

Comment: Если вы указали, что `chat/js` и `chat/css` являются каталогами статики, значит и пути нужно указывать относительно этих самых каталогов, то есть `{% static 'ChatLogic.js' %}` и `{% static 'chat-style.css' %}` соответственно

Comment: `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` — если вы указали относительный путь, значит путь к статике вычисляется не относительно корня сайта, а относительно текущей ссылки, что скорее всего неверно

Comment: Я понял, а что посоветуете сделать с путями? У меня js правильно и без ошибок подключился к html, а css не хочет. Выдает ошибку Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/conversations/static%20'chat-style.css'%20%7D' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Стоит ли мне как-то по-другому указать в settings.py пути в STATICFILES_DIRS или STATIC_URL?